# How to run video in iPhone web?

Tags: iphone, html

i make iPhone web which need to play video.i use video tag for video play but that's not work in iPhone

Comment: Place a code you wrote. Does your code use a flash player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be in the wrong format - this article is a very comprehensive overview of html5 video: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

Apple say:

> "The following compression standards are supported:
>
> H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps.
>   Note that B frames are not supported in the Baseline profile. MPEG-4
>   Part 2 video (Simple Profile) AAC-LC audio, up to 48 kHz Movie files
>   with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp are supported."

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html